# Null value returned from valid sql query. Doctrine unable to execute query with @ variables?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently trying to get the rank of a player based on their amount of wins/loss. I'm using the following sql:

```
 "SELECT rank FROM(SELECT playerid,@r:=@r + 1 rank FROM leaderboard        
          ORDER BY leaderboard.wins desc, leaderboard.loses asc) t1,
  (SELECT @r:=0) t2
  WHERE playerid=$userId"
```

The results appears to be valid when execute in mysql.

However, when I'm trying to run this in Doctrine under Symfony 2. The value of the column rank is always null.

```
$em = $this->em;
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT rank FROM
                                 (SELECT playerid,@r:=@r + 1 rank FROM leaderboard
                                   ORDER BY leaderboard.wins desc, leaderboard.loses asc
                                 ) t1,(SELECT @r:=0) t2
                                 WHERE playerid=$userId");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

A var_dump of $results prints the following:

```
array (size=1)
    0 => 
       array (size=1)
          'rank' => null
```

Copy-pasting the value of $statement->getWrappedStatement() in MySql Workbench returns the right value.

Would that be because of the variable @r?